# How to do numeric iterators in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have to convert Java code to angularjs ..In java i used `while` loop for numeric iterator something like below and in angularjs i tried `ng-repeat` but its not worked as loop sometime increase by +1 or +2 etc.Can someone please guide ho to do numeric iteration in angularjs?

```
 int curretPos = 0;
 String namePattern ="SOmeValue";

        while (curretPos < namePattern.length()) {
          String featureName = "";
          if (Constants.namePatternformat.charAt(0) == namePattern.charAt(curretPos)
            && Constants.namePatternformat.charAt(1) == namePattern.charAt(curretPos + 1)) { // name pattern

            curretPos = curretPos + 2;
            int nextPos = namePattern.indexOf(Constants.namePatternformat.charAt(2), curretPos);

            if (nextPos != -1) {
              featureName = namePattern.substring(curretPos, nextPos);
              curretPos = nextPos;
              if (features.containsKey(featureName)) {
                name = name.concat(String.valueOf(features.get(featureName)));
              } else {
                throw SomeException;
              }
            } else {
                 throw SomeException;
            }
          } else if (Constants.namePatternParent.charAt(0) == namePattern.charAt(curretPos)
            && (Character.toLowerCase(Constants.namePatternParent.charAt(1)) == Character.toLowerCase(namePattern.charAt(curretPos + 1)))) { // parent name pattern

            if((namePattern.length() - curretPos) >= Constants.namePatternParent.length()) {
              if (!Constants.namePatternParent.equals(namePattern.substring(curretPos, (curretPos+Constants.namePatternParent.length())))) {        
                  throw SomeException;
              }
            }else{
                 throw SomeException;
            }

            curretPos = curretPos + (Constants.namePatternParent.length() - 1);

            if(null != parent){
              name = name.concat(parent);
            }

          } else if (Constants.namePatternIncrement.charAt(0) == namePattern.charAt(curretPos)
            && (Character.toLowerCase(Constants.namePatternIncrement.charAt(1)) ==  Character.toLowerCase(namePattern.charAt(curretPos + 1)))) { // increment name pattern

            if((namePattern.length() - curretPos) > Constants.namePatternIncrement.length()) {
              if (!Constants.namePatternIncrement.substring(0, 5).equals(namePattern.substring(curretPos, curretPos+5))) {
                  throw SomeException;
              }
            }else{
                 throw SomeException;
            }

            curretPos = curretPos + (Constants.namePatternIncrement.length() - 2) + 1;

            int nextPos =
              namePattern.indexOf(Constants.namePatternIncrement
                .charAt(Constants.namePatternIncrement.length() - 1), curretPos);

            if (nextPos != -1) {
              featureName = namePattern.substring(curretPos, nextPos);
              curretPos = nextPos;

              if (features.containsKey(featureName)) {
                if (null != features.get(featureName)
                  && features.get(featureName).matches("^-?\\d+$")) {

                  int currentInstance = Integer.valueOf(features.get(featureName)) + (instance-1);
                  name = name.concat(String.valueOf(currentInstance));
                } else {
                     throw SomeException;
                }
              } else {
                  throw SomeException;
              }
            } else {
                 throw SomeException;
            }
          } else {
            name = name.concat(String.valueOf(namePattern.charAt(curretPos)));
          }
          curretPos = curretPos + 1;
        }
```

Comment: what about using javascript `while`? Why would you need ng-repeat here?

Comment: @smnbbrv Do you mean rather then doing in angular i will write pure JS?